# providing default implementation for method in abstract class

Tags: dart

In the example below I was hoping *sum* getter would return 8, but it is a compile error.

```
Class 'B' has no instance getter 'sum'.
```

According to the spec:

> Using an abstract class instead of an interface has important
>   advantages. An abstract class can provide default implementations; it
>   can also provide static methods, obviating the need for service
>   classes such as Collections or Lists, whose entire purpose is to group
>   utilities related to a given type.

What is the correct way to provide a default implementation of sum that adds x and y?

```
abstract class A {
  int get x;
  int get y;
  int get sum => x+y;
}

class B implements A {
  int get x => 3;
  int get y => 5;
}

main() {
  B b = new B();
  print(b.x);
  print(b.sum); // Not working, why not 8?
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to make `B` *extend* `A` instead of *implement*.

```dart
abstract class A {
  int get x;
  int get y;
  int get sum => x+y;
}

class B extends A {
  int get x => 3;
  int get y => 5;
}

main() {
  B b = new B();
  print(b.x);
  print(b.sum); // displays 8
}
```

Alternatively if you don't want to use *extends* because your class may already extend an other class, you can use [mixins](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/mixins/) :

```dart
abstract class M {
  int get x;
  int get y;
  int get sum => x+y;
}

class A {
  String s = "s";
}
class B extends A with M {
  int get x => 3;
  int get y => 5;
}

main() {
  B b = new B();
  print(b.s);
  print(b.x);
  print(b.sum); // displays 8
}
```

Comment: You can't use mixin if M also extends other class

Answer (score 2):

Another way around this issue is to just use extensions (depending on your use case). This way all your default method implementations will work regardless if you extend, implement, mixin, ect.

```
abstract class A {
  int get x;
  int get y;
}

class B implements A {
  int get x => 3;
  int get y => 5;
}

extension E on A {
  int get sum => x+y;
}
main() {
  B b = new B();
  print(b.x);
  print(b.sum); // 8
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By choosing to implement A, you have to implement everything A requires even if you have provided default implementations. If you want to use default implementation from A while having the flexibility to provide your own implementations you have to use A as a [mixin](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/mixins/):

```
class B with A {
  int get x => 3;
  int get y => 5;
}
```